# iPad 1 app stuck in portrait rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I sent a build over Testflight with the Supported Interface Orientations set to Landscape.

Client's iPad 1 (iOS 5.1) is stuck in Portrait mode even with the auto-lock off.

Any idea why this happens?

Works fine on my iPad 2.

Comment: Are you implementing `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` on all the relevant view controllers, in addition to the new iOS 6 autorotation methods?

Comment: iPad is stuck (meaning all apps) or your particular app is stuck? The first is a malfunctioning iPad. The second: are you also on iOS5? Some things about this changed in iOS6.

Comment: iOS5. It works fine on my iOS6 iPad 2.
I'll try shouldAutorotate; i don't think I need new iOS6 autorotation methods since it is on iOS5